# Is there a class that models "patches"?

Tags: haskell, discrete-mathematics, monoids, semigroup

I'm looking for a class in like the following in a Haskell library (or at least to know the mathematical name for such a thing):

```
class Monoid patch => MyThing patch t where
  applyPatch :: t -> patch -> t
```

I can have instances like this:

```
instance MyThing (Last t) t where
  applyPatch x patch = case getLast patch of
    Just y => y
    Nothing => x
```

But I could also have instances like this:

```
instance MyThing (Dual (Map key value)) (Map key value) where
  applyPatch x patch = ...
```

Where the patch essentially adds and/or replaces key/value pairs from the map.

One could go further if you wanted to do deletions:

```
instance MyThing (Dual (Map key (Maybe value))) (Map key value) where
  applyPatch x patch = ...
```

Aside from `patch` being a monoid, the main law I want this class to follow is associativity, concretely:

```
forall (x :: t, y :: patch, z :: patch). 
  (x `applyPatch` y) `applyPatch` z == x `applyPatch` (y <> z)
```

My thought (well, actually ChatGPTs thought) that this was an ["Affine Space"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-AffineSpace.html), but the issue is that my underlying "patch" type, whilst a monoid, is not an additive group, because it doesn't have inverses.

So basically I think I want an affine space without inverses. Does this exist, either mathematically or in a Haskell library?

Comment: You say it performs additions and replacements - but not deletions ("tombstones")?

Comment: In the base case, if you just replace `t` with `Maybe t` you've got deletions. In the map case, I've added an extra instance which models deletions to the question body. Just need to add `Maybe` to the patch `value`

Comment: My Haskell is very rusty, but it's idiomatic in Haskell to use immutable data, rather than mutate structures in-place (and annoyingly, Haskell lacks _ergonomic_ record types) - in the case where data is immutable then I'd describe [this as a "projection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics)) rather than a "patch".

Comment: Kudos to ChatGPT for suggesting affine space! Indeed, an affine space can be considered as a manifold upon which a symmetry group acts, which is just another special case of a monoid action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have described amounts to a monoid (or semigroup) action. One place where a class for that can be found is [`Data.Monoid.Action` from *monoid-extras*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.6.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Action.html):

```
class Action m s where
    act :: m -> s -> s
```

Paraphrasing the documentation, the laws are:

```
act (m1 <> m2) = act m1 . act m2
-- Also, if m is a monoid:
act mempty = id
-- Additionally, if s has some algebraic structure then act m preserves it.
-- For instance, if s is a monoid, then act m should be a monoid homomorphism.
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a functor: `Action m a` = `FunctorOf (Basically m) (->) (Const a)` and the laws are an example of the Functor laws!

Comment: Where [`newtype Basically m a b = Basically m`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/gf54o6/monoids_as_oneobject_categories_or_not/) lifts a Monoid to a Category: `instance Monoid m => Category (Basically m)`.

Comment: You know what `act mempty = id` wears on a first date? A class action law suit.

Comment: @Iceland_jack Yup -- the action as a functor from the single-object category to Hask (and then made to fit `Category`/`FunctorOf` through phantoms). Also, a homomorphisms are functors as well (phrasing it in this style, from `Basically m` to `Basically n`), and in particular an action is a homomorphism to `Endo s`.